# How do I find a domain server on my client right away?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

This is a problem that I noticed. I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server and joined it to my windows 7 client.

Now when I am trying to reach my "share" that i created in the Win2008 server, it does not show up at the Network tab in Windows 7. Instead, the only way I found it was to manually type in \\myserverlocation in the run prompt.

Is there any way to find my share right way without doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just creating a persistent [drive mapping](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3673.html)?

Comment: yeah I know, but the first time the user is trying to find the share, it wont show up without typing in the servername. I dunno, maybe this is just how it is?

Comment: For the most part, that's just how it is. You could make a logon script to map the drive, though. That would solve the problem for first-time users.